# Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, title, markdown-preview, mathjax

When you are asking a question - or making a suggested edit - you can see the preview of the post, but not a preview of the title. This does not matter that much on the sites without [MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/mathjax/info) - after all, Markdown is not allowed in the title, so the title will be the same as what you see in the edit window.

But if the site uses MathJax, the rendered version can look rather differently. And it is quite easy to make a mistake - one then needs to edit the title again after posting the question (or submitting a suggested edit).

Since it seems that [some changes to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033) are planned anyway, perhaps the developers could look at this, too.

This has been requested before on various per-site metas:

- MathOverflow Meta: [Feature request: question title should appear above question preview](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4883)
- Mathematics Meta: [Why not add the title of the question in the preview while writing it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25252), [Latex preview on question title?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20248), [How to fix botched title edit?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23389)
- Physics Meta: [Preview the title when asking a question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1419)

Comment: Workaround tip: Write the title as the first line in the body, then cut/paste into the title space. Unrelated tip: When jaxing extremely complicated equations upload an image (screenshot) and place it at the top of the body, work on the equation at the top of the body (causing it to render directly under the edit window, so you don't have to scroll down to check it); after it exactly matches the image cut/paste it into the body where it's supposed to be located and delete the image.

Comment: And ideally the preview should show the title in the same font size as will appear when finally posted.